# VHDL; How do I constrain a unconstrained std_logic_vector within a constrained array

Tags: vhdl

Consider the following

```
type foo is (A, B, C);
type foo_vector is array (foo) of std_logic_vector;
```

How do I constrain *foo_vector*? It seems like the compiler should be able to constrain the signal if I give it defaults.

```
signal bar : foo_vector : (others => x"0000");
```

But the compiler just continues to say "Signal cannot be unconstrained"

If that's the case then how can I constrain this signal?

```
signal bar : foo_vector(?)(15 downto 0);
```

I am using the Lattice compiler.

Alternatively, If I do

```
type baz_vector is array (natural range <>) is std_logic_vector;
```

And I try to constrain the signal by doing this:

```
signal baz_vector_signal : baz_vector(1 downto 0)(15 downto 0);
```

The code compiles. So I know that the compiler is capable of handling unconstrained arrays (VHDL2008).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code snippets don't provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

You're attempting to provide an element constraint for the element of type std_logic_vector while the array index is already constrained.

That's possible:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package cjc_pkg is
    type foo is (A, B, C);
    type foo_vector is array (foo) of std_logic_vector;
    signal bar: foo_Vector (open) (3 downto 0) := (others => (others => '0'));
end package;
```

using an array constraint found in IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.3.2 Array types, 5.3.2.1 General, (the BNF) in the subtype indication for the declaration of signal `bar`:

> constrained_array_definition ::=
>   **array** index_constraint of *element_*subtype_indication

subtype_indication is defined 6.3 Subtype declarations and consist of a optional resolution indication, type mark and constraint. Here we are dealing with the unconstrained element.

From 6.3:

> constraint ::=
>         range_constraint
>       | array_constraint
>       | record_constraint
>
> element_constraint ::=
>         array_constraint
>       | record_constraint

which bounces us back to 5.3.2.1:

> array_constraint ::=
>         index_constraint [ array_element_constraint ]
>       | ( **open** ) [ array_element_constraint ]
>
> array_element_constraint ::= element_constraint
>   ...
>   index_constraint ::= ( discrete_range { , discrete_range } )
>
> discrete_range ::= *discrete_*subtype_indication | **range**
>
> An array constraint may be used to constrain an array type or subtype (see 5.3.2.2 and 6.3).
>
> An array object is characterized by the number of indices (the dimensionality of the array); the type, position, and range of each index; and the type and possible constraints of the elements. The order of the indices is significant.

You can use (**open**) as a space holder to skip over a constrained index preserving the order significance of the constrained index.

The example will analyze with a -2008 compatible VHDL implementation.

Comment: Thank you, I find it amazing how you seem to know the VHDL standard in such detail. I made a mistake in putting axs_std_logic instead of std_logic_vector but I think you already found it. I checked the code and it compiles. Appreciate it

Comment: The -2008 standard is big and complex enough knowing where to find things takes practice. Stackoverflow provides the opportunity for inculcation. The rest is not making statements of 'fact' without first verifying.