# VHDL, aliasing part of a unconstrained array

Tags: vhdl

Consider the following code,

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package pkg is
    type foo is (A, B, C);
    type foo_vector is array (foo) of std_logic_vector;
    signal bar: foo_Vector (open) (31 downto 0) := (others => (others => '0'));
end package;
```

How can we do aliasing of bar such that the aliased signal only contains part of each std_logic_vector? For example if we only want to take like 4 bits out of bar?

```
alias partial_bar is bar(open)(3 downto 0);
```

According to 
[VHDL; How do I constrain a unconstrained std_logic_vector within a constrained array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59002897/vhdl-how-do-i-constrain-a-unconstrained-std-logic-vector-within-a-constrained-a/59003324?noredirect=1#comment104326460_59003324)
It seems like the (open) should be able to preserve the order, but it is not the case. my compilation fails.

Comment: You can't alias it if it's not a valid slice name.  See IEEE Std 1076-2008 8.5 Slice names "A slice name denotes a one-dimensional array composed of a sequence of consecutive elements of another one-dimensional array." Note `alias partial_bar is bar(A)(3 downto 0);` would work where the one-dimensional array being sliced is bar(A) and the elements are consecutive. Also **open* is neither a subtype indication or a discrete range, it's prior use is as a placeholder in supply constraints to signal bar.

Comment: ok understood. Thank you again!

Comment: seeing your other question, is this question still open?